# Calling an array in another function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, return

Sorry if this is a dumb question, having a mind blank

```
function getPassedUsers(){
  var rr = ['a'];

  return _ARRAY_OF_PAST_USERS
}

function removeFromFutureUsersArray(users){
  getPassedUsers();
  console.log(rr);
};
```

why does that return undefined and how can I get the second function to log the contents of the array created in my other function?

Comment: What do you expect? What is `_ARRAY_OF_PAST_USERS`? `rr` isn't in scope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understood, following code should do what you want:

```
function getPassedUsers(){
  var rr = ['a'];
  return rr;
}

function removeFromFutureUsersArray(users){
  var rr = getPassedUsers();
  console.log(rr);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Well rr belongs to the function getPassedUsers, so removeFuteureUserArray cannot see it.  I assume your wanting something like this ->

```
function getPassedUsers(){
  return ['a'];
}

function removeFromFutureUsersArray(users){
  var rr = getPassedUsers();
  console.log(rr);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You should read about the SCOPE:

```
var a=0;
{
var b=1;
alert(a);//0
alert(b);//1
}
alert(a);//0
alert(b);//undefined
```

A variable can only  be accessed inside of its scope. So between { and }
So in your case you either have to pass it to the other function, or make it gobal:

```
var rr;
function func1(){
rr=["test"];
}
function func2(){
console.log(rr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In JS if you need only a single point of access to the required function set then a simple closure will do the job. This can simply be implemented as follows;

```js
function passedUsers(){
  var rr = [];
  return { getPassedUsers  : function(){return rr;},
           insertPassedUser: function(u){rr.push(u)},
           removePassedUser: function(u){rr.splice(rr.indexOf(u),1);}
         };
}
var pu = passedUsers();
pu.insertPassedUser("john");
pu.insertPassedUser("jane");
console.log(pu.getPassedUsers());
pu.removePassedUser("john");
console.log(pu.getPassedUsers());
```

However if you need to access those functions from an indefinite number of objects while keeping the closure intact (`rr` is available to all), then a prototype involving more complicated solution would be better.